# Excel Concatenate on large number of columns

Tags: excel

I want to concatenate a large number of cells starting from A2 to BC2. I really do not want to keep adding commas and write every cell address like =CONCATENATE(A2,B2.....).
I tried using =CONCATENATE(A2:BC2) but it returned VALUE! Error.
Any other way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Try CONCAT(A2:BC2) instead

Comment: It returns an Error #NAME?

Comment: I guess you have a version of Excel < 2019 / 365, as that function was introduced in 2019? Do you have any errors in that range of cells?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid manually building very long formulas, and since you don't have the `CONCAT` function, here are two options:

**Option 1**

- A "helper row"

  In some empty row in your worksheet, enter the formulas:

```
    eg:  A5: =A2
         B5: =A5&B2
```

- Then select `b5` and fill right to `bc5`.  `bc5` will contain the desired result.

**Option 2**

Write a User Defined Function (UDF) in VBA:

To enter this User Defined Function (UDF), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select Insert/Module and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this User Defined Function (UDF), enter a formula like `=vbaTEXTJOIN(,,A2:D2)` in some cell.

Note that the function has optional arguments for a delimiter, and whether to ignore empty cells in the concatenation, mimicing the `TEXTJOIN` function, which arrived along with `CONCAT`.  But you still must enter at least blank entries (note the extra commas), even if you want to accept the defaults.

```
Option Explicit
Function vbaTEXTJOIN(Optional sDelim As String = "", Optional ignoreEmpty As Boolean = True, Optional sJoin) As String
    Dim I As Long, V, sTemp As String

Select Case IsArray(sJoin)
    Case True
        Select Case ignoreEmpty
            Case True
                For Each V In sJoin
                    sTemp = sTemp & IIf(V = "", "", sDelim) & V
                Next V
                    sTemp = Mid(sTemp, Len(sDelim) + 1)
            Case False
                For Each V In sJoin
                    sTemp = sTemp & sDelim & V
                Next V
                    sTemp = Mid(sTemp, Len(sDelim) + 1)
        End Select
    Case False
        sTemp = sJoin
End Select

vbaTEXTJOIN = sTemp
                
End Function
```

**Examples of above methods**

[image]